# How to determine if one json-schema is a subset of another?

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

Say I have two json-schemas - is it possible (in python or anywhere else) to determine if one is a subset of another?

I am looking for a function on two json-schemas that will return true if and only if every instance accepted by the first json-schema is also accepted by the second.

For a super simple example, suppose my schemas are

```
int_schema = {'type': 'integer'}
num_schema = {'type': 'number'}
```

Then I would have

```
subset(int_schema, num_schema) = True
subset(num_schema, int_schema) = False
```

Don't really care about this being python, I am more trying to find out if json-schema supports this.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only project I found that does what you want is [this Javascript implementation](https://github.com/haggholm/is-json-schema-subset).

A Python implementation (or even a comand line utility) would be so useful considering JSON Schemas really shine when back-end and front-end communicate, and JavaScript is not the most popular backend language, but is a very popular front-end one.

If anyone feel inspired out there, a pushdown automaton would be the perfect tool for that exact task !

Another approach would be to write a [meta schema](https://json-schema.org/specification.html#meta-schemas) for the `num_schema` and try to validate the `int_schema` against it. Meta schema are self-descriptive and you can validate other schemas against them (hence *meta*).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python implementation with `Pydantic` support - [isjsonschemasubset](https://github.com/leontrolski/isjsonschemasubset). *Disclaimer: author*.

From the docs:

```py
from isjsonschemasubset import dump, issubset, load

json_schema_a = load(path_to_a)
json_schema_b = load(path_to_b)

for error in issubset(json_schema_a, json_schema_b):
    ...
```